# Посоветуйте простое решения сортировки кто больше всего использует SWAP. (Linux)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сервер, память

**Посоветуйте** п**ростое решения сортировки кто больше всего использует** SWAP

Решения HTOP TOP Скрипты не подходит хотелось альтернативы ....

Comment: Напишите вопрос на русском языке, пожалуйста. Сейчас ничего не разобрать

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вариант .....

---

```
apt install -f smem
```

---

```
> smem -s
```

---

```
known fields:

command  process command line
maps     total number of mappings
name     name of process
pid      process ID
pss      proportional set size (including sharing)
rss      resident set size (ignoring sharing)
swap     amount of swap space consumed (ignoring sharing)
user     owner of process
uss      unique set size
vss      virtual set size (total virtual memory mapped)
```

---

```
smem -s swap

 PID User     Command                         Swap      USS      PSS      RSS
 1021 root     /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0       36    37300    43227    56176
 .............................
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно прочесть в каталоге `/proc/[0-9]*/` файлик status

Там смотри 2 строчки:

```
Name:   gvfsd-burn
.....
VmSwap:        0 kB
```

Составляй список и сортируй